# Load div one by one with a delay using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is my whole code..what I am trying to do is to have-. when DOM is ready first div shows on page and second one after a delay and then third one and so on up to 150.

Problem with the current code is that, whole 150 div loads at once after a small delay.

`My code` -

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Test for dashed div</title>
<style type="text/css">
.dashdiv
{
    width: 150px;
    height: 50px;
    background: #ae2d3e;
    float:left;
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 6px #d4a7b0;
    margin: 5px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <?php
    for($i =0; $i < 150; $i++)
    {
    ?>
    <div class="dashdiv">
    This is a div text
    </div>
    <?php   
    }
    ?>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('div.dashdiv').each(function()
    {
          $(this).hide().delay(1000).fadeIn(1850);
    });
});
</script>   
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem you're facing, which no one has mentioned, is that jQuery `delay()` is only chainable on an fx queue. So, using it after `hide()` will not work. A quick fix to get it working would be to use an effect in place of `hide()`, ie:

```
$('div.dashdiv').each(function(i) {
  $(this).fadeOut(0).delay(1000*i).fadeIn(1850);
});
```

Answer (score 5):

Try using the `index` argument that is automatically assigned for every iteration of `each` to extend the delay in a linear manner:

```
$('div.dashdiv').each(function(i) {
   $(this).delay(1000*i).fadeIn(1850);
});
```

Also, following your comment, the style of the `div` elements should be changed to make them hidden:

```css
.dashdiv {
    display:none;
    ...
}
```

Comment: the only problem with the code is it first loads whole 150 div at once and then fadeout and then starts adding one by one

Comment: @swapnesh Followed your example. To achieve what you've described, just add `display:none` to the style rule of `.dashdiv`. This also means that the `hide()` method is redundant here.

Comment: @swapnesh Edited the answer in accordance.

Answer (score 2):

You can use :

Html:

```
<div id="parent">
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$('#parent .child')
    .hide()
    .each(function(index){
        var _this = this;
        setTimeout( function(){ $(_this).fadeIn(); }, 5000*index );
    });
```

demo at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/eGWx9/1/

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to delay and fadeIn a `div` only once the previous `div` has finished.
It uses the fadeIn callback to move to the next div in the array:

```
// hide all
$('.dashdiv').hide();

// fade in each div one by one
divs = document.getElementsByClassName('dashdiv');
(function fade(i){
    if(i < divs.length){
        $(divs[i]).delay(1000).fadeIn(1850, function(){
            fade(++i);
        });
    }
})(0);
```

Or without `getElementsByClassName`.

```
// hide all
$('.dashdiv').hide();

// fade in each div one by one
(function fade(i){
    if(i < $('.dashdiv').length){
        $($('.dashdiv')[i]).delay(1000).fadeIn(1850, function(){
            fade(++i);
        });
    }
})(0);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/louisbros/RdxS6/

Comment: What's the point of using vanilla JS `document.getElementsByClassName` if you're already using jQuery fadeIn function?

Comment: Why does it matter? You could easily use $('.dashdiv') in it's place if you wanted to. To me it is more readable.

Comment: **It matters**. It's called consistency. When you work as part of a team you'll learn not to think with the "to me" mentality. You're already using a library to sit between you and the JS functions. If there's no need to use JS functions directly, don't. Writing everything with JS is a different story of course. So @DiH is correct, this is not a matter of "Why not?" it's a matter of "Why?".

Comment: I don't agree. jQuery is not designed to replace JS functions, it is a library.