# How to call a function (each) after completion (change)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to call (each) after completing the function change. My script add list the  files from the input file field and I would like to show the files one by one after finishing it [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15772529/load-div-one-by-one-with-a-delay-using-jquery). My code does not work, what am I doing wrong?

```js
$('.drop-input').on('change', function(){
    /* ... */
    var data = $(this)[0].files;
    $.each(data, function(index, file){
       var fRead = new FileReader();  
       fRead.onload = (function(file){  
          return function(e) {
              $('.append').append('<img src="'+e.target.result+'" class="drop-file" />');
          };
        })(file);
        fRead.readAsDataURL(file);
    
    });
    
    /* ... */

}).each('.drop-file',function(i) {
     $(this).delay(1000*i).fadeIn(1850);
});
```

```css
.drop-file{
    width:100px;
    display:block;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="file" class="drop-input" multiple />
<div class="append"></div>
```

Comment: did you get any errors?

Comment: [Doc's example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/onload) should help.

Comment: Check out [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49343356/how-to-call-a-function-each-after-completion-change/49343499#49343499) for a detailed explanation @URB.

Answer (score 0):

There are some problems in your code, the most important of which is the TypeError caused by the following piece of code, which essentially makes the code break completely:

```
}).each('.drop-file',function(i) {
     $(this).delay(1000*i).fadeIn(1850);
});
```

What you're trying to do with the above piece of code can be easily integrated inside the event handler you set for the `load` event. You only need to do the following:

- Create a counter outside the loop that will be incremented by each loaded file.
- Set a style with `display: none` to the created image, because when created, it's already visible due to the CSS rule of the `drop-file` class.

**Snippet:**

```js
/* ----- JavaScript ----- */
$('.drop-input').on('change', function() {
  /* Create a counter to use for the delay. */
  var counter = 0;
  
  /* Iterate over every file selected. */
  $.each(this.files, function(index, file) {
    /* Create a new file reader. */
    var fRead = new FileReader();
    
    /* Set the 'load' event. */
    fRead.onload = (function(file) {
      return function(e) {
        /* Create a new image and append it to the '.append' div. */
        var img = $("<img>", {
          "src": e.target.result,
          "class": "drop-file",
          "style": "display: none"
        }).appendTo(".append");
        
        /* Use the counter to fade the image in. */
        img.delay(1000 * counter++).fadeIn(1850);
      };
    })(file);
    
    /* Read the file as a data url. */
    fRead.readAsDataURL(file);
  });
});
```

```css
/* ----- CSS ----- */
.drop-file {
  width: 100px;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!----- HTML ----->
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" class="drop-input" multiple/>
<div class="append"></div>
```